# Calculating Average Width of Specific Dark Region

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am processing a large portion of images that are similar to the one below. I'd like to be able to calculate an average width of the black line (roughly the yellow line in the image), but am not sure how best to accomplish this in python. The yellow line itself is not present on the images, just the black bands.

[image]

**The original image:**

[image]

Comment: How is the dark band defined? It doesn’t seem the darkest part of the image. Is it always right above a  right band? Is it always a dark band of a specific width range? Detecting the band is 99% of the problem, once detected it is easy to get the width. So we need to know the logic to use to identify the band.

Comment: The dark band itself is a "wear band" on a drill bit. So the width of the band is quite dynamic depending on the level of usage the drill bit has experienced. The dark band is always above the white band. You are right that it's typically not the darkest part of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is using `line-detector`.

---

- Find the edges of your image

  - ```py
    img = cv2.imread('calculate_width.png')
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    canny_img = cv2.Canny(gray_img, threshold1=150, threshold2=200)
    ```
  - [image]
- Detect the lines

  - ```py
    lines = createFastLineDetector(_length_threshold=20).detect(canny_img)
    ```
- Calculate the distance

  - ```py
    for cur in lines:
        (x1, y1, x2, y2) = cur[0]
        dist = math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) ** 2) + ((y2 - y1) ** 2))
        print("Distance between ({:.2f}, {:.2f}) - ({:.2f}, {:.2f}) = {:.2f}"
              .format(x1, y1, x2, y2, dist))
        cv2.line(img, pt1=(x1, y1), pt2=(x2, y2), color=(0, 255, 0),
                 thickness=2)
        cv2.imshow("detected", img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
    ```
- Result

  - [image]
  - ```py
    Distance between (46.98, 884.00) - (50.37, 905.10) = 21.37 pixel
    ```

**Update**

---

If we apply the `image-segmentation` we have to the following area:

[image]

- We want to find the length of the red lines and find the distance between the red-lines using the formula.

The upper:

[image]

```py
Distance between (118.06, 868.42) - (96.92, 871.40)
Distance between (95.94, 872.67) - (75.85, 876.11) 
Distance between (74.88, 877.33) - (24.85, 886.16) 
Distance between (23.96, 887.62) - (0.01, 890.06)
```

The lower:

[image]

```py
Distance between (79.07, 894.60) - (99.02, 892.15)
Distance between (104.01, 886.54) - (125.99, 887.20)
Distance between (40.93, 901.45) - (66.05, 898.40)
Distance between (0.00, 906.02) - (33.99, 905.52)
```

If you randomly select two points: `(66.05, 898.40)` and `(24.85 - 886.16)`, the distance will be: `41.23`

The solution is not perfect, but it might give an intuition for a better idea. Therefore I'm posting as an answer.

Code:

```py
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np
from cv2.ximgproc import createFastLineDetector

img = cv2.imread('calculate_width.png')
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 150, 255,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
sure_bg = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel)
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening, cv2.DIST_L2, 5)
_, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform, 0.3*dist_transform.max(),
                           255, 0)
sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)
unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg, sure_fg)

lines = createFastLineDetector(_length_threshold=20).detect(unknown)

for cur in lines:
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = cur[0]
    dist = math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) ** 2) + ((y2 - y1) ** 2))
    print("Distance between ({:.2f}, {:.2f}) - ({:.2f}, {:.2f})"
          .format(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    cv2.line(img, pt1=(x1, y1), pt2=(x2, y2), color=(0, 255, 0),
             thickness=2)
    cv2.imshow("detected", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ahx. The yellow line in the OP was just to mark the black line that I am trying to calculate the average distance of, and is not present in the actual images I'm processing. Based on your answer it looks like the yellow line needs to be present since for the calculations? I will update the OP to make that more clear.

Comment: I thought the yellow line is available. So do you have the template image?

Comment: Just added it to the OP @Ahx. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: No, no problem.

Comment: Apologies for the late follow up. With some slight modifications, this worked for my use case, thanks!